# Horizontal scroll fail, help me fix the mess please

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to make the page scroll horizontally when scrolling down (example - http://hotdot.pro) however the only script that I can seem to come up with works however it will keep on scrolling, I know why it does keep scrolling however I would like some help at coding it correctly :) JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0aks9u5d/

```
var xyz = 1;


        $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollD = $(document).scrollTop();    

        xyz= xyz+1;

        console.log(xyz);    

        $("html, body").scrollLeft(xyz);
        $("html, body").scrollTop(0);    

    });
```

Any help is great Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got there is called infinite recursion loop.

The  `$("html, body").scrollLeft(xyz)` fires your `$(document).scroll(function(){...})` event. The event body has `$("html, body").scrollLeft(xyz)` which fires `$(document).scroll(function(){...})` again. And so on...

Comment: What would be the best way of achieving the same result but not making it loop?

Comment: How can I make it not check for scrolling but scrolling up and down? $(document).scrollTop()

Comment: The right way of doing it is implementing a `mousewheel` event instead of `scroll`  – https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/ , so the events don't call each other.

Comment: Im trying to do it without plugins

Comment: I give up I will just use the mouse wheel, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, `mousewheel` is right and easy way. You have to separate those events. But here's how you do it without plugins: https://jsfiddle.net/maxflex/g7497yeb/

Comment: Ohh great thanks, it works much better than my if statement way - https://jsfiddle.net/0aks9u5d/1/